# settings tab is missing in sonarqube dashboard for Administrator

Tags: sonarqube

In `SonarQube 3.7.4`, unfortunately I have removed sonar-administrator, sonar-user in the `settings->users->administrator` part. so now I'm not able to get the "Settings" tab for Administrator.

so please suggest how to get back the Settings tab in the SonarQube dashboard for Administrator.

Comment: Hi Folks,Please kindly reply to the issues. It's very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to install the same version e.g. in a vm. Then you can export the `users` table and replace the broken one.